# what is use of package_data in setup.py (python setuptools)

Tags: python, setuptools, egg, python-wheel

What is use of package_data in setup.py (python setuptools)

Can you please give an example?

Is it possible to add a dependency .whl or .egg file as package_data, if yes, how do you automatically run that file?